# What is the error in following PL/SQL Trigger Code

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t_for_debit
BEFORE UPDATE 
ON account
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.acc_bal>0)
DECLARE
amt ACCOUNT.ACC_BAL%TYPE;
BEGIN
    select acc_bal into amt from account where accno=:old.accno;
if :old.acc_bal-:new.acc_bal then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PREVIOUS AMOUNT ->'||:old.acc_bal||' DEDUCE BALANCE ||:new.acc_bal||' NEW BALANCE IS ' ||:old.acc_bal-:new.acc_bal );
else
    insert into loan values(:old.acc_name,:old.acc_bal-:new.acc_bal,:old.accno)
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TXN SUCCESSFULLY BUT DUE TO DEBIT MONEY MORE THAN ACCOUNT MONEY');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('WE OPENED YOUR LOAN ACCOUNT. PLEASE FEED THE LOAN BEFORE FURTHER USE');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('LOAN CUSTOMER NAME '||:old.acc_name||' HAVING LOAN AMOUT '||:old.acc_bal-:new.acc_bal||' ASSOCAITE WITH '||:old.accno || '        ACCOUNT NO');
END IF;
END;
/
```

When I compiled this code on SQL*Plus command prompt then following error showing.

```
6/93     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "NEW" when expecting one of the
         following:
         ) , * & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem =>
         <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
         like4 likec as between from using || member submultiset
```

Comment: Your single quotes are not balanced.  You are missing one after `DEDUCE BALANCE`.

Comment: i done that but it still saying
8/1      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
8/77     PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: You're assuming there's only one error, which is incorrect. When you fix the first, the compiler will tell you about the second. When you fix the second, the compiler will tell you about the third, and so on. At the beginning of each message the line and character-within-the-line where the parser detected the error are given - for example, `6/93' means "line 6, 93d character in the line". `8/1` means "line 8, first character". Oracle's error messages are not always the clearest, but with some effort I'm sure you'll figure it out. As a hint - line #1 is the `DECLARE` statement. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were several issues with your code.

- `if :old.acc_bal-:new.acc_bal  THEN ..` is not a valid statement
  it is modified to

  `if :old.acc_bal-:new.acc_bal > 0 THEN`

Your trigger will compile with above change, However.

- `select acc_bal into amt` statement will raise an error `ORA-04091: table  HR.ACCOUNT is mutating, trigger/function may not see it`. This will happen when you run an update statement on account table. In the context of the trigger it is not required as we can get all the required values from `:old.acc_bal and :new.acc_bal` . So, it is commented.
- You cannot concatenate a result of a numerical difference with a string inside `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE()`. It will throw an exception `ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error`. So, Here i changed the code to store the result of the difference into the `amt` variable and re-used it in `DBMS_OUTPUT`.

  ```
  SET DEFINE OFF
  SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t_for_debit
  BEFORE UPDATE 
  ON account
  FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN (new.acc_bal > 0)
  DECLARE
  amt ACCOUNT.ACC_BAL%TYPE; 
  BEGIN
  amt := :old.acc_bal-:new.acc_bal;
      --select acc_bal into amt from account where accno = :old.accno;
  if amt > 0 then
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PREVIOUS AMOUNT ->'||:old.acc_bal||' DEDUCE BALANCE '||:new.acc_bal||' NEW BALANCE IS ' || amt);
  else
      insert into loan(acc_name,acc_bal,accno)  values(:old.acc_name,:old.acc_bal-:new.acc_bal,:old.accno);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TXN SUCCESSFULLY BUT DUE TO DEBIT MONEY MORE THAN ACCOUNT MONEY');
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('WE OPENED YOUR LOAN ACCOUNT. PLEASE FEED THE LOAN BEFORE FURTHER USE');
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('LOAN CUSTOMER NAME '||:old.acc_name||' HAVING LOAN AMOUT '||amt||' ASSOCAITE WITH '||:old.accno || '        ACCOUNT NO');
  END IF;
  END;
  /
  ```

Here is the output for the else condition.

```
     1 rows updated.
     TXN SUCCESSFULLY BUT DUE TO DEBIT MONEY MORE THAN ACCOUNT MONEY
     WE OPENED YOUR LOAN ACCOUNT. PLEASE FEED THE LOAN BEFORE FURTHER USE
     LOAN CUSTOMER NAME INV HAVING LOAN AMOUT -1 ASSOCAITE WITH 1        ACCOUNT NO
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I want to point out the result of the SELECT statement is not used, so it should be removed.

The error is in the IF expression

```
if :old.acc_bal-:new.acc_bal then
```

The expression must evaluate to a **boolean** value. The expression `:old.acc_bal - :new.acc_bal` is a numeric result. I suspect you meant `:old.acc_bal > :new.acc_bal`.